# Remove carryover multiple-line spacing before paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013

I have a long document that is in **single-line spaced** paragraphs, with **Space Before** paragraphs of 10 points.

At a few locations, I have inserted **bullet points**, and set these in **multiple 1.15 spaced** lines.

Multiple-line spacing adds extra space after each line in the paragraph, including the last line, so it adds to what I've specified in my "space before" setting on the next paragraph.  This makes the gap between the last bullet and the next regular paragraph larger than those in the rest of the document.

How do I force the gap before paragraphs following bullets to be consistent with the rest of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multi-line spacing controls spacing after each line within a paragraph (including the last line of the paragraph).  Multi-line spacing is a paragraph-level setting, you can't set different values within a paragraph.  So if this setting is more than single-line spacing, the extra spacing will also appear at the end of the paragraph.

If you don't want the additive extra space, you will need to reduce the "space before" on the next paragraph to offset the extra multi-line space.  How many points that extra fractional line is equivalent to depends on the font.

To determine the needed adjustment:

- Take a big paragraph with single-line spacing and use the on-screen ruler and your cursor to measure from the bottom of the characters in the first line to the bottom of the characters in the last line (use the character baseline, ignore descenders).
- Divide that measurement by the number of lines included in it (exclude the first line because you started below it).
- The result is the height of one line (fraction of an inch), for your font.  Multiply that by 72 points per inch.  That will convert the measurement to points.
- If you are using 1.15 line spacing for the bullets, that adds 0.15 of a line at the bottom of the paragraph.  To convert that to points, multiply the 0.15 by the points per line.
- Subtract that from the "space before" setting on the next paragraph.

Here's an example.  Right now, I only have access to Word 2007 running in Wine on Linux, so the features and display are a little limited.

[image: screenshot]

My default font is Calibri 11 pt.  The paragraph is set to single line spacing, zero space before and after the paragraph.   Ignore the squiggly underline that appears under everything in the screenshot, it's the spelling checker because I used nonsense text for the example.

The ruler on the left side isn't very readable and the cursor isn't showing up on it, so I used another approach:

- Insert a rectangle, using `Insert Shapes` from the menu.
- Draw it from just below the bottom edge of the first line to just below the bottom edge of the last line.  You can use the object handles to fine-tune its size and position.
- The shape information shows the rectangle height as 0.75 inches, and the box covers four lines.  So each line has a height of 0.1875 inches.
- At 72 points per inch, that's 13.5 points for single-line height.
- If the line spacing is set to 1.15, it is adding an extra 0.15 line space.  Multiplying 13.5 points per line by 0.15 lines gives you 2 points as what is being added.
- You're using a different font, so you will get slightly different results.  However, the settings are in whole points (fractional point differences will be undetectable), so I suspect yours will round to the same adjustment.
- In my case, I would subtract 2 points from the "space before" setting on the subsequent paragraph, setting it at 8 points instead of 10.

Comment: Sorry ignore the previous comment. Hit enter by mistake. Maybe it's new in Office 2016 but Space After and Space Before are merged from what I see. So if Space After is 4 and Space Before is 6, the total gap will be higher of two -- 6. As for my question, the tweak I found is: manually hit enter for the very last line to separate it into new paragraph, turn it into single spaced paragraph. Still causes a slight shift in formatting though I'm noticing, even though all the paragraph space is supposed to come below, not above.

Comment: I don't have access to Office 2016, but the merging you describe would have a lot of ramifications, the least of which would be properly rendering legacy documents.  It isn't clear why Microsoft would change basic behavior like that.  You might want to verify it with large before and after settings to confirm what you think you're seeing.  (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd)  The manual Enter sounds like a workaround for the line spacing, but it also affects other things, like recognition of bullet text, justification, etc.  It would be cleaner to work within Word's design.  Figure out the line spacing properly once, then it's trivial to use it as needed, and you won't need to workaround other things that get thrown off.  What I described should give you what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying what you advised but I cannot figure out how to do it. My scale is in inches, I can't use it to measure correctly, and worst of all I'm on a Surface tablet with no keyboard or mouse. Could you help me figure out what I need? My font is size 10 Cambria. The normal "Space Before" I am using is 10 points for Single Spaced paragraphs and this particular issue paragraph is Multiple 1.15 and all in bullets. What do I reduce 10 to? I always use the grid view to edit, never the scale. The scale has all these options on top left that I can't figure out, so I just leave it alone.

Comment: Just noticed your comment.  I'll edit the answer with some instructions.

Answer (score 0):

> > Maybe it's new in Office 2016 but Space After and Space Before are merged from what I see. So if Space After is 4 and Space Before is 6, the total gap will be higher of two -- 6. <<

In Word 2016, if you go to Options>Advanced> and check the box in "Layout Options" that says "Don't use HTML paragraph auto spacing" then it WON'T simply take the larger of the 2 spacings and instead combines them (as the author is more likely to have intended).